# Link between the dimension of the image of a linear application and the minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a linear application $\phi : \mathbb R^6 \rightarrow \mathbb R^6$, and I have given its minimal polynomial : $t^2 (t^2+1)(t-1)$.

> how can I find the dimension of the image of phi?

Sorry if the question is trivial, i'm still learning :) I thought that maybe there is a link with the dimension of the eigenspaces but I figure this out...

Comment: The best you can do is bound the dimension of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the polynomial, all its eigenvalue are $i,-i,1,0$. Consider its canonical form, there are two possible answers 4 or 5. the former one means an extra eigenvector to $0$, the latter to $1$. The following are two possible matrix.The first 2-dimensional block is for $x^2+1$, $1$ in the third row for $x-1$, the next 2-dimensional block for $x^2$. the last row can be eigenvalue $0$ or $1$ and can not be $i$ or $-i$ because in real form, imaginary eigenvalue will appear with a pair.

\begin{equation*}
\left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right ]
\left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right ]  
\end{equation*}

Comment: Excuse me can you develop a little bit? As I said Im learning and I m following you and your thoughts

Comment: why is the dimension of the image influenced by the minimal polynomial ?

Comment: From the minimal polynomial, we can learn about the form of biggest Jordan blocks. although $i$ and $-i$ are not real, we can make it a "real form", that is

Comment: [0 1 1 0],(OK in comment I can not give a matrix. then, $x^2$ means the biggest Jordan block of 0 is 2-dimensional, $x-1$ means biggest Jordan block for $1$ is 1-dimensional, then we have decide 5 dimension of the matrix. the left one may be of eigenvalue 0 or 1.

Comment: In fact, you can decide not only the dimension but also all possible canonical forms of a matrix.